# How can i pass a parameter to jmeter with ant?

Tags: jenkins, ant, jmeter

i'm running jmeter through ant but i need to pass a parameter. In a console app i would do "JLocalDB=1" when launching jmeter. But with ant i have no idea how to add this parameter to my launch command. What ever i try it doesn't work.

Here's what i tried with build.xml: 
Add this:

```
        <property name="localDB" value="0"/>
```

In Jmeter tag. Ant marks the test as failed but didn't even launch it.

Add this:

```
        <jvmarg value="-JlocalDB=0"/>
```

In jmeter tag. Simply fails. Does nothing.

Add this:

```
<jvmarg value="-DlocalDB=0"/>
```

In jmeter tag. Does nothing, ant doesn't launch the test and says it failed.

Since i'm running with jenkins i tried putting in the launch params of ant both JlocalDB/DLocalDB/LocalDB nothing works.

Is the product half finished? Every answer i see says to do exactly what i did which obviously doesn't work.

It works perfectly if i launch jmeter via cmd and pass the parameter there. But with ant... nothing works. Unless i remove the parameter and start with default values....

Any idea what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter Ant Task documentation](https://github.com/jfifield/ant-jmeter#nested-elements):

> `jmeterarg`    Use to specify additional JMeter command line arguments. The only attribute is value.

So try providing it as `<jmeterarg value="-JlocalDB=0"/>` setting like:

```
<target name="run">
    <echo>funcMode = ${funcMode}</echo>
    <delete file="${testpath}/${test}.html"/>
    <jmeter
        jmeterhome="${jmeter.home}"
        testplan ="${testpath}/${test}.jmx"
        resultlog="${testpath}/${test}.jtl"
        jmeterlogfile="jmeter-ant.log">
        <jmeterarg value="-JlocalDB=0"/>
```

I quickly verified it using [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and the following [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) code:

```
println('localDB property value is: ' + props.get('localDB'))
```

and the property seem to be applied

[image: JMeter Ant Property]

Comment: Then it's jenkins fault cause it's not working either. I'm done i'm putting the default value to the parameter.  losing time cause it's not tested.. fml